# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string when select date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want date to be displayed as yyyy-mm-dd. The value in the table for date is dd/mm/yyyy. I have run the query

```
select CONVERT(DATE, FORMDATE, 103) from UPDATELOG
```

and i got error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string". Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: mysql or Sql Server?  They are different things.

Comment: Know your RDBMS. `mysql` <> `sql-server`. This, however, looks like T-SQL as `CONVERT` has a style code. Please update your tags, but also add at least a couple of sample values.

Comment: It means you have bad date in your data. Not all the dates are in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. Which version of sql server you are using ? Also stop storing dates as strings to avoid such problems in future

Comment: The root of your challenge here is that you are storing dates as strings. You should always use the date/datetime datatypes when storing dates. That is why those datatypes exist. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Answer (score 1):

This certainly looks like SQL Server.  So, use `try_convert()` instead:

```
select TRY_CONVERT(DATE, FORMDATE, 103)
from UPDATELOG  ;
```

To get the values that fail, use:

```
select FORMDATE
from UPDATELOG
where TRY_CONVERT(DATE, FORMDATE, 103) is null
```